# Converting a masked numpy array into a csv file

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, netcdf

I am having trouble converting a netCDF file (which is a masked numpy array) into a csv file. The netcdf file was condensed from 12 separate files to form a 3D array of 12 x 52 x 39, where 12 corresponds to the months, 52 to the latitudes and 29 longitudes.

UPDATE:
My desired csv output is 4 columns with grid number (0-437), latitude, longitude and total precipitation. e.g:

```
grid number| latitude| longitude| Total_precipitation
0             60.5000  -1.2345     800.123
1              .         .           .
2              .         .           .
```

I want to sum my 12 months of precipitation and condense the data into a single column. (I haven't found any answers on here to help me do this)

At the moment I have managed to read in the netCDF file and save it as csv but it is in the wrong format (see method 1-3).

This is what I have so far:

```
###################
# importing modules
###################
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
#import csv
from netCDF4 import Dataset



  #setting up directory 
    CURRENT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
    precip_path = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR + '/CLIM8Splash/input/futureCLIM8/precip_2070_2099CDF') 
    sys.path.append(precip_path) 

    # reading  precip netcdf 
    os.chdir('CLIM8_splash/input/futureCLIM8/precip_2070_2099CDF/')
    files = ['jan_precip_2070_2099CDF.nc', 'feb_precip_2070_2099CDF.nc', 'mar_precip_2070_2099CDF.nc', 'apr_precip_2070_2099CDF.nc','may_precip_2070_2099CDF.nc', 'jun_precip_2070_2099CDF.nc', 'jul_precip_2070_2099CDF.nc', 'aug_precip_2070_2099CDF.nc', 'sep_precip_2070_2099CDF.nc', 'oct_precip_2070_2099CDF.nc', 'nov_precip_2070_2099CDF.nc', 'dec_precip_2070_2099CDF.nc']
    #all_precip = ma.zeros((len(files), 52, 39))
    all_precip = np.zeros((len(files), 52, 39))
    all_precip.fill(np.nan)
    for idx, x in enumerate(files):
        ds = Dataset(x, 'r')
        precip = ds.variables['cdf_precip_dmean_tmean_abs'][:, :]
        all_precip[idx, :, :] = precip
        ds.close()
    os.chdir('../../../..')

#dimensions of netCDF file
def altReadin(path):
    my_file = Dataset(path)
    print(my_file.file_format)
    print("Dimensions: " + str(my_file.dimensions.keys()))
    print(my_file.variables['rlon'])
    content = MFDataset(path, False, 'rlon')
    print(content.variables['cdf_precip_dmean_tmean_abs'][:]) 
    print("Variables: "+ str(my_file.variables.keys()))

    altReadin(FILE_PATH)

    #####OUTPUT
    NETCDF3_CLASSIC
    Dimensions: [u'rlat', u'bound', u'rlon']
    <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
    float32 rlon(rlon)
        bounds: bounds_rlon
        topology: circular
        long_name: longitude in rotated pole grid
        standard_name: grid_longitude
        units: degrees
        modulo: 360.0
        axis: X
    unlimited dimensions: 
    current shape = (39,)
    filling off

    [[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
     [-- -- -- ..., 5.498641490936279 5.392685890197754 --]
     [-- -- -- ..., 5.66285514831543 -- --]
     ..., 
     [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
     [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
     [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]]


       Variables: [u'rlat', u'bounds_rlat', u'rlon', u'bounds_rlon', u'lat', u'lon', u'cdf_precip_dmean_tmean_abs', u'rotated_pole', u'meaning_period', u'time', u'em_scen', u'percentile']

#Totalling 12 months of precipitation 
#????

# and then converting it to a csv
precip_tot = precip

#Method 1 saves csv with grid shape preserved
np.savetxt("precip_fut1.csv", precip, delimiter=",")

#Method 2 csv as a long string
precip_tot.sum(axis=0).filled().tofile('precip_tot_fut.csv', sep=',')

#Method 3 netcdf>dataframe>csv (still preserves shape)
precip_tot = pd.DataFrame(precip_tot)
precip_tot.to_csv("precip.csv")

#sample of output of precip
>>> >>> [[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., 7.167891502380371 6.648772716522217 --]
 [-- -- -- ..., 7.282683372497559 -- --]
 ..., 
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]]
print(precip_tot.head()
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  ...  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  \
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   
3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   
4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   

         36        37  38  
0       NaN       NaN NaN  
1  7.167892  6.648773 NaN  
2  7.282683       NaN NaN  
3  7.517180       NaN NaN  
4       NaN       NaN NaN  

[5 rows x 39 columns]
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: We need to know more about `precip`, shape, dtype, some sample values.  And a sample of the files, explaining what's right or wrong.  If `savetxt` works, I'd stay away from `tofile`; you have less control over format.

Comment: I just tried a `savetxt` on a `ma.MaskedArray` - it wrote the  `data`, ignoring the mask.  You may need to use `filled` to modify that behavior.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj I have made edits to my post, so hopefully it should be clearer.

Comment: What's the `csv` supposed to look like?  Who or what will read it?

Comment: @hpaulj I want the csv to have 4 columns (grid number, latitude, longitude and total precipitation) of length 438  'cells'. With this csv file it will be read into R to perform RLQ analysis. Apologies if I wasn't entirely clear, I am new to using python.

Comment: And what about the masked values?

Comment: They can be ignored, as I don't want to retain an array/grid shape as with a netCDF. So as it is now it's a grid 52x39 = 2028 cells but only 438 have values the rest are NaNs.

Comment: If you got wrong `shape`, why not `reshape` bevor saving? Please explain more detailed _**is in the wrong format**_. Show example of your **expected format**.

Comment: Hi @stovfl see my update.

Comment: May I see `print(precip_tot.head())` and `print(precip.head())`.

Comment: I never know why people want to turn a beautiful structured format like netcdf where each variable has full metadata into a CSV file.  The only possible reason could be if they want to read it into EXCEL, but there is no reason to do this. EXCEL can't handle the lat/lon effectively and if you want to make map plots or timeseries, virtually every software can read the netcdf directly and make plots (python, R, GRADS, ncl, idl, gdl, matlab etc etc).  If you want to average over the 12 months, you can do this in a single line with cdo timmean in.nc out.nc

Comment: Didn't see any usefull, where are your _**latitude| longitude| Total_precipitation**_ data?

Comment: Hi @stovfl the latitude and longitudes are associated with each precipitation value in the form a netCDF. The columns are longitude cells and rows are latitude cells.

Answer (score 1):

Consider these Dataframe, *Dimensions are reduced for brevity*.

**Example Data**:

```
lat(5,)[ 60.5  61.5  62.5  63.5  64.5]
lon(4,)[-0.2345 -1.2345 -2.2345 -3.2345]
preceip(5, 4)[[        nan         nan         nan         nan]
 [        nan         nan  5.49864149  5.39268589]
 [        nan         nan  5.66285515         nan]
 [        nan         nan         nan         nan]
 [        nan         nan         nan         nan]]
```

**Your Data**:

```
lon = ds.variables['rlon'][:, :]
lat = ds.variables['rlat'][:, :]
precip = ds.variables['cdf_precip_dmean_tmean_abs'][:, :]
```

Read `precip array`, append not null data:

```
precip_list = []
precip_tot = 0
for r in range(len(lat)):
    for c in range(len(lon)):
        if precip[r,c] > 0:
            precip_list.append((lat[r], lon[c], precip[r,c]))
            precip_tot += precip[r,c]

precip_list.append(('', 'precip_tot:', precip_tot))

fieldnames = ['grid number', 'latitude','longitude', 'Total_precipitation']
print('{fn[0]}\t{fn[1]}\t{fn[2]}\t{fn[3]}'.format(fn=fieldnames))
for i, d in enumerate(precip_list[:-1]):
    print('{:<10}\t{:>8.4f}\t{:>9.4f}\t{:10.3f}'.format(i, d[0], d[1], d[2]))
print('{}precip_tot:\t{:10.3f}'.format('\t'*6, precip_tot))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
>    grid number    latitude    longitude   Total_precipitation
>     0            61.5000      -2.2345        5.499
>     1            61.5000      -3.2345        5.393
>     2            62.5000      -2.2345        5.663
>                             precip_tot:     16.554
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: I tried that but I get an error: IOError: master dataset .../ECOFLORA/CLIM8_splash/input/futureCLIM8/precip_2070_2099CDF/*_precip_2070_2099CDF.nc does not have a aggregation dimension

Comment: Does this help:NETCDF3_CLASSIC
Dimensions: [u'rlat', u'bound', u'rlon']
<type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 rlon(rlon)
    bounds: bounds_rlon
    topology: circular
    long_name: longitude in rotated pole grid
    standard_name: grid_longitude
    units: degrees
    modulo: 360.0
    axis: X
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (39,)
filling off

[[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., 5.498641490936279 5.392685890197754 --]
 [-- -- -- ..., 5.66285514831543 -- --]

Comment: Thanks @stovfl apologies I have only just seen your response. I haven't seen your approach before.

Comment: @Saz: Seems I forgetting to notify you. Report back if it's working or helpful.